# How to intent the remaining text from the starting of the text using the UIWebview in swift?

Tags: html, iphone, xcode, swift4, wkwebview

I am using the following code for the WKWebview for showing the HTML code . The code is as follows:

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController,WKNavigationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
//        load remote url
//        let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!
//        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
//        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true

//        load local html file
        loadHTMLStringImage()
    }

   func loadHTMLStringImage() -> Void {
       let htmlString = "<p>•    This is a small string.</p><p>•  This is a more of medium string with few more strings.</p><p>• Well this is certainly a bigger string with more words than either of the previous two strings.</p>"
       webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
   }
```

It works well and it shows the output as:

[image]

But the remaining text follows the position from where the bullet point is starting which i don't want. What I need is to get the text indented with the start of the text above. Like it is in the picture:
How to achieve like the following shown below in the image?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using paragraph in your HTML, You can use lists to solve your problem.

Here is the reference to the list from w3schools
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_list-style-position

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your issue in two way:

1. Use `</br>` after `</p>`.
2. Or can use a list in instead of paragraph tag as follow.

```html
<ul>
<li>Your first paragraph </li>
<li>Your 2nd paragraph </li>
<li>Your 3rd paragraph </li>
</ul>
```